# Iframe problems with Gmail

Tags: html, iframe, gmail

I'm pretty new to coding, and am trying to make a small chrome extension that displays my gmail in an Iframe. I'm having several problems: I have to sign in with google inside my Iframe, and the gmail will refuse to display when I try loading the extension. Keep in mind, the iframe works fine with websites like "https://ifunny.co", but it will refuse to work with anything Google.

My html box that pops up with the click of the extension button:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!---body>
<iframe src="https://ifunny.co" style="border:2px solid black;" height="500" width="350"></iframe>
</body--->
<body>
<iframe src="https://mail.google.com" style="border:2px solid black;" height="500" width="350" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I <iframe> Gmail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325208/how-can-i-iframe-gmail)

Comment: The iframe shows up blank completely.

Comment: Never mind, just found out gmail doesn't allow iframes. thanks guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display <iframe> tag to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976966/how-to-display-iframe-tag-to-gmail)