# HTML IFrame not working when being used in Gmail

Tags: python, html, gmail

I have a script which automatically sends mail to users. Here's the script - even though I don't think it's relevant to the question:

```
import smtplib
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage

EMAIL_ADDRESS = email
EMAIL_PASSWORD = noIAmNotShowingYouMyPassword

userEmail = email
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Title'
msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = userEmail

msg.set_content('This is a plain text email')
html = open('email.html', 'r').read().format(userEmail = userEmail)
print(html)
msg.add_alternative(html, subtype='html')


with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

The email.html file is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: large; align-items: center;align-content: center;text-align: left;border: 100px;box-shadow: 20px;">
        <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Hey there, {userEmail}!
            <h3>

                <p>Want an appeal? Fill the form below, or click the button to go to the Google Form website.</p>
                <button href="googleFormLink">Head to the site</button>
                <iframe src="googleFormEmebedLink" width="700" height="520" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

My issue is the `<iframe src="googleFormEmebedLink" width="700" height="520" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>`, which doesn't show up.
The button does though, however it doesn't work.
I suspect it's security matter on Google's side, but I want to confirm. Also, I need a way to fix this issue.
I've checked on an online HTML viewer, it worked perfectly fine. Below are images showing the Gmail VS the HTML Viewers' results.[image: HTML VIEWER]

[image: GMAIL]

Comment: Does this help: [Stackexchange Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6736/is-it-possible-to-include-an-iframe-in-a-gmail-message)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display <iframe> tag to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976966/how-to-display-iframe-tag-to-gmail)