# Embedding a playable video in gmail without using iframes

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail, html-email

I am trying to use google apps script to send an email embedded with a youtube video. I have tried producing some code, following the samples provided on google's website. I can't get the `iframe` to show. The code sample provided here, sends an email but with the just the hyperlink, but doesn't show the embedded video. I tested the `html` code separately, and it seems to be fine.( I see now that this initial approach doesn't work, see **edit**).

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('embed_video');
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
Logger.log(doGet().getContent())
function testSchemas() {
  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject: 'Test Email - ' + new Date(),
      htmlBody:  doGet().getContent()
    });
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

Here is the `html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
     <a href="http://google.com">Click Me!</a> <!--this shows up in the email-->
     <iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" width="560" height="315" src="url" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe> <!--this doesn't show up in the email-->
   </div>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976966/how-to-display-iframe-tag-to-gmail) was just pointed out to me, and it seems `<iframes>` is off limits. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16977311/10906987) seems to suggest

> .. an `<a>` wrapped around an `<img>` or thumbnail.

But this would not produce a playable video (?)but only a link to one which is what I wanted ideally. Is there anyway to embed a playable video then that doesn't use `iframes`?

Comment: What you want is simply not possible. Email service providers only support a specific subset of html elements - unsupported tags such as `iframe` are filtered out.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I am guessing there is no alternative to `iframe` that is supported and will let me embed playable video either?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail then https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-youtube/

Comment: @Rubén Thank you. that seems like a promising solution!

Comment: @jcp there is an article on [campaign monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/video-in-email/) that has step by step of what you are after.

Comment: @Rubén AMP might be a good way to go but support is not there yet, plus this is not a duplicate of iframe. There are ways to add videos in emails with fallbacks (link above) without the need of iframe which is what OP is after. Sorry if I sound direct but just pointing out that this question was closed off before any email devs got to it I guess.

Comment: @Syfer I didn't say that AMP is a duplicate of iframe.

Comment: @Rubén typo. I meant this question should not have been closed because of iframe reference.